# Question about solvable cocompact subgroups in linear algebraic group over a finite extension of the p-adic numbers

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, topological-groups

Let $Q_p$ be the p-adic numbers, where p is any prime number. Then $Q_p$ is a locally compact, Hausdorff, totally disconnected (non-discrete) topological field.
Let $GL(n,Q_p)$ be the general linear group over $Q_p$ equipped with subspace-product p-adic topology. So $GL(n,Q_p)$ is a locally compact, Hausdorff, totally disconnected (non-discrete) topological group. Does $GL(n,Q_p)$ contain a solvable cocompact subgroup which is **closed** in the p-adic topology?

Similarly, if $k$ is a finite extension of the p-adic numbers $Q_p$, does every linear algebraic group over $k$ have a solvable cocompact subgroup which is **closed** in the topology coming from $k$? (not in the Zariski topology)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{Q}_p)$ acts transitively on the variety of complete flags, which is compact, and the stabilizer of a point is the set of upper triangular matrices, which is solvable and cocompact. The same holds with $\mathbf{Q}_p$ replaced by any non-discrete locally compact field.

Comment: Dear Yves, Thanks. It is surprising that it is true for ALL local fields.
By the way, do you know any books/papers about structure of linear algebraic group over non-archimedean local fields of characteristic p (for p any given prime number)?

Comment: No... I don't even know a reference for the following (very likely) fact: for any non-discrete locally compact field $K$ and every algebraic $K$-group $G$, the group $G(K)$ has a cocompact solvable subgroup.

Comment: If characteristic is zero look at Proposition 9.3 in "A. Borel and J. Tits: Groupes reductifs"
For GLn case look at page 13 Lemma 5 in "GUENTNER, HIGSON and WEINBERGER: THE NOVIKOV CONJECTURE FOR LINEAR GROUPS"

Comment: If chac(F)=0, it is true that G(K) has a cocompact solvable subgroup from Borel and Tits.
For any local field F, GL(n,F) has a cocompact solvable subgroup from GUENTNER, HIGSON and WEINBERGER

Comment: @m07kl: that the group $GL(n,F)$ has the upper triangular group as cocompact solvable subgroup is well-known and was obviously known in the 60s when Bruhat and Tits developed their theory much before Guentner-Higson-Weinberger (btw I don't see anything related in their paper).

Comment: Look at page 13 Lemma 5 in
http://www.personal.psu.edu/ndh2/math/Papers_files/Guentner,%20Higson,%20Weinberger%20-%202005%20-%20The%20Novikov%20conjecture%20for%20linear%20groups.pdf

Comment: OK, they prove something more precise actually. Anyway I maintain that the cocompactness of the upper triangular subgroup was known much before, by many people.

Comment: Dear Yves
If I want to make a reference to the fact that the group GL(n,F) (F is ANY local field) has the upper triangular group as cocompact solvable subgroup, to which paper of Bruhat and Tits I should refer.

Comment: I don't claim they proved it, I claimed they knew it. One way you can do is to write something like: "it is well-known that the upper triangular group is cocompact in $GL(n,F)$ (for instance, because it is the stabilizer of a point in the transitive action on the variety of complete flags)".

Comment: what is the argument for the fact you mentioned:for any non-discrete locally compact field K and every algebraic K-group G, the group G(K) has a cocompact solvable subgroup?

Comment: I claimed this only when $K$ has characteristic zero (although I believe it works in general). Basically I use a minimal parabolic in the reductive case, and in general I get one modulo the unipotent radical and pull it back. The cost is a few minor technicalities I'm lazy to develop right now. An alternative argument is to show that, using the adjoint representation, there is a closed orbit in the flag variety; then point stabilizers are cocompact solvable subgroups.